# Unable to connect web parts using powershell

Tags: 2010, powershell, sharepoint-server, web-part-connection

I am trying to connect a custom webpart (provider) to a ReportViewerWebPart (consumer) programmatically, using a Powershell script.

I get the error message below when I execute the following line:

```
$wpConnection = $webpartmanager.SPConnectWebParts($wpProvider, $providerConnectionPoint, $wpConsumer, $consumerConnectionPoint, $transformer)
```

Error message:

> Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPageUserException: The
>   transformer type
>   "Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.TransformableFilterValuesToFilterValuesTransformer" is not allowed to be used on this page.

Does anyone know what may be causing the error and how to fix it? Similar code works when I run it as a Visual Studio application.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try the following:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb ($siteurl) 
$list = $web.Lists["Web Part Gallery"] 
$wpManager = $web.GetLimitedWebPartManager($web.Url + "pages/pagename.aspx",[System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared); 
$wpl = $list.Items | where {$_.Title -eq "Your Webpart Name"} 
$xmlReader = New-Object System.Xml.XmlTextReader($wpl.File.OpenBinaryStream()); 
$errorMsg = "" 
$webPart = $wpManager.ImportWebPart($xmlReader, [ref]$errorMsg) 
$wpManager.AddWebPart($webpart,"Header",1) 
$wp2 = $wpManager.WebParts | Where {$_.Title -eq "LeftMarginFilterWebPart"} 
$conWP = $wpManager.GetConsumerConnectionPoints($webpart)[0] 
$provWP = $wpManager.GetProviderConnectionPoints($wp2)[0] 
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint") 
#if these are ootb web parts you need to set the trans up and call the overloaded SPConnectWebParts with $trans as the last param 
#$trans = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPRowToParametersTransformer 
#trans.ConsumerFieldNames = new string[] {"Category"}; 
#trans.ProviderFieldNames = new string[] {"Title"}; 
$newCon = $wpManager.SPConnectWebParts($wp2,$provWP,$webPart,$conWP) 
$wpManager.SPWebPartConnections.Add($newCon); 
$wpManager.Dispose() 
$web.Dispose()
```

Original Post:
http://xopherdesign.com/SitePages/Posts.aspx?PID=5

Comment: Thank you @Supermode for the response. I have tried your code with few modifications but ran into an error: **The provider connection point "Parameter Value" on "Page" and the transformer do not use the same connection interface.**

Comment: My Provider web part has interface type: **Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ITransformableFilterValues**
<br/>And the Consumer web part (Microsoft.ReportingServices.SharePoint.UI.WebParts.ReportViewerWebPart) is of 
InterfaceType             : **Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.IFilterValues**

Comment: @jensPM. I am facing the same issue. Did you get to resolve the issue. If yes, can you please help me out with this..